# Root user to execute a script without privilege but allow sudo commands to run without password

Tags: sudo, su

So as root (in `/etc/rc.local`) I want to run a script without root privileges say using su

```
su - myuser -c myscript
```

but in the myscript I want to run a command with `sudo` without giving a password. However I don't want to let myuser run that command without a password otherwise (as in don't want to add to sudoers etc.)

Is this even possible?

Comment: Doesn’t sound like it. You want the user to be able to do something that requires a password without providing a password. Alternatively, you want the user to do something without a password while requiring the user to use a password. Clearly there is a better way to do whatever it is you are trying to do. [XY Problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 1):

If the required command is not within a block (eg loop or conditional), then you can split the script into three: the preceding commands run as `myuser`, the protected command run with `sudo` (which doesn't prompt when already `root`) and the remaining commands, also run as `myuser`:-

```
su - myuser -c myscript-preamble
sudo myscript-protected-command
su - myuser -c myscript-postamble
```

More generally, there is a trick that you can use with `sudo`, using the saved credentials:-

```
sudo -u myuser sudo -S true <<< password 2>/dev/null
su - myuser -c myscript
sudo -u myuser sudo -k
```

There are a number of considerations - these are the first that come to mind:-

- The script (or at least the first line) must be executed in a read-protected file (`-rwx------`) or an execution-protected directory (`drwx------`), both owned by `root`.
- The trick requires that `sudo` credentials are remembered for a defined time (a normal default) and that `sudo` in `myscript` runs within that time.
- If `myuser` runs `myscript` while `root` is simultaneously running it, the remembered credentials will be used if the `sudo` command is reached before `root` runs `sudo -k`.

As you can see, it is not an ideal solution from a security standpoint, but it may be workable in your environment.

Otherwise, you will need to use `sudo -A`, as described in this extract from the `sudo` manual:-

```
 -A, --askpass
             Normally, if sudo requires a password, it will read it from the user's
             terminal.  If the -A (askpass) option is specified, a (possibly graphical)
             helper program is executed to read the user's password and output the password
             to the standard output.  If the SUDO_ASKPASS environment variable is set, it
             specifies the path to the helper program.  Otherwise, if sudo.conf(5) contains
             a line specifying the askpass program, that value will be used.  For example:

                 # Path to askpass helper program
                 Path askpass /usr/X11R6/bin/ssh-askpass

             If no askpass program is available, sudo will exit with an error.
```

To implement this you will need to write a program which checks if it's running as `root`: if so, it outputs the password for `myuser` (from obfuscated data, of course); otherwise, it prompts for the password as normal and outputs the user's response.

So yes, it *is* possible to do what you want, but may involve a fair amount of work, depending on the level of security you require.